# Store ChangeList object for access in later requests

Tags: django

I'm trying to store a ChangeList object that I need access to in another (ajax) request. I need to get the (filtered) queryset from the changelist. This is (parts of) the code:

```
class TimeReportEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        changelist = ChangeList(request, self.model, self.list_display, self.list_display_links, self.list_filter,
                        self.date_hierarchy, self.search_fields, self.list_select_related, self.list_per_page,
                        self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)

    # i'd like to store the changelist object here
    ...
```

I've tried storing the ChangeList object in the cache with:

```
   cache.set("time_report_changelist_%s" % request.user, changelist, 0);
```

This gives me a PicklingError: `Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed`

And storing in in the session doesn't work:

```
request.session["time_report_changelist"] = changelist
```

This gives me a TypeError: `<django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList object at 0x1051da890> is not JSON serializable`

Perhaps there's a completely different approach to this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, you certainly need a different approach, but it's impossible to tell what as it isn't at all clear what you want to achieve. Why do you want to store it? Exactly what will you do with it in the other request?

Comment: I want to get access to the queryset that has been filtered with `list_filter`s in the Django admin, a la: `filtered_query_set = changelist.get_queryset(request)`